# How to synchronize cells animation

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, swift5

I'm trying to simulate a shimmering animation in each cell of a UICollectionView.

When I start the app it works fine:

[image]

But when I scroll to the left each cell gets itself animation:

[image]

What I want is when I to scroll it to left, it works like the first image. For a while, I've just put this code below to do the animation:

```swift
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let cell = cell as? ShimmeringCell else { return }
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0, options: [.autoreverse, .repeat], animations: {
            cell.alpha = 0.4
        }, completion: nil)
    }
```

This is the full code: [Github](https://github.com/edualb/Swift_examples/blob/master/shimmeringTest/shimmeringTest/ShimmeringViewController.swift)

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

To solve this issue, I had to create a new `UIView` and add this in a subview of `UICollectionView`:

```swift
    let newCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
        // Here was creating a collectionView
        return collection
    }()

    let viewExample: UIView = {
        // Here was creating a new view
        return view
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        newCollectionView.delegate = self
        newCollectionView.dataSource = self
        newCollectionView.register(ShimmeringCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        self.view.addSubview(self.newCollectionView)
        setupCollection()
    }

    private func setupCollection() {
        // Constraints...

        self.newCollectionView.addSubview(self.viewExample)
        setupViewExample()
    }

    private func setupViewExample() {
        // Constraints...
    }
```

After that, I just put the animation in this view:

```swift
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        newCollectionView.delegate = self
        newCollectionView.dataSource = self
        newCollectionView.register(ShimmeringCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        self.view.addSubview(self.newCollectionView)
        setupCollection()

        self.viewExample.alpha = 0.6
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse, .allowUserInteraction], animations: {
            self.viewExample.alpha = 0
        }, completion: nil)
    }
```

It's resulted:

[image]

Thanks for all and see you somewhere on the world.

Github with this solution: [Github](https://github.com/edualb/Swift_examples/blob/master/shimmeringTest/shimmeringTest/ShimmeringViewController.swift)